# Нужно ли учитывать асинхронность если параллельный процесс полностью загружает движок браузера?

Tags: javascript, асинхронность

Ситуация такая: инициализация объекта занимает значительное время из-за того, что нужно произвести много подсчетов. Для продолжения следующих этапов алгоритма объект должен быть уже полностью инициализирован.
Если отнестись а процессу инициализации как к асинхронному, то нужно использовать колбэк функцию (для того, чтобы гарантировать, что следующие этапы не будет выполняться до полной инициализации).
На практике я вижу, что этого не требуется. То есть асинхронизм не проявляется. На сколько я понимаю, дело в том, что поскольку движок браузера уже полностью загружен (инициализацией) он не начинает выполнения других строк кода.
Вопрос: грамотно ли поступать так и во всех ли браузерах это будет работать так?

[Пример кода:](https://jsfiddle.net/mcga5uyz/)

```
Array length: <span id='result'></span><br />
Может ли случится такое, что подсчет числа членов массива произойдет до его полного инициализирования?
<script>
function fibonacci(n) {
   if (n < 2){
     return 1;
   }else{
     return fibonacci(n-2) + fibonacci(n-1);
   }
}

var array  = [];

function init(){
  for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
    array[i]=fibonacci(37);
  }
}

init();
$('#result').text(array.length);
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mcga5uyz/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> На практике я вижу, что этого не требуется. То есть асинхронизм не
>   проявляется. На сколько я понимаю, дело в том, что поскольку движок
>   браузера уже полностью загружен (инициализацией) он не начинает
>   выполнения других строк кода. Вопрос: грамотно ли поступать так и во
>   всех ли браузерах это будет работать так?

Дело не в том, что движок загружен, а в том, что JS однопоточный.

У вас никаких асинхронный операций нет, `Web Worker` не используете. Логично, что всё будет выполняться последовательно. И к моменту `$('#result').text(array.length);` всё будет проинициализировано в любом браузере.

**P.S.** У вас для всех элементов массива всегда `fibonacci(37)` одно и тоже.

Этот вариант быстрее:

```
function init(){
  var fiba = fibonacci(37);
  for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
    array[i] = fiba;
  }
}
```

Comment: "Этот вариант быстрее" -- я думаю тут fibonacci (с экспоненциальной сложностью) специально для демонстрации используется, чтобы сделать инициализацию медленной.

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение. Понял, что асинхронность в js может быть только в случае таких вещей как setTimeout, ajax, Web Worker.  Мысль о загруженности движка пришла в голову из-за того, что даже строки, предшествующие процессу инициализации? не выполняются до его завершения (то есть браузер, на самом деле, загружен работой). Но в Вашей правоте убедился тем, что даже если посереди процесса инициализации, [вставить какой-нибудь confirm()](https://jsfiddle.net/s976/mcga5uyz/1/) - ничего от этого не меняется.